# Crystal Report scale to fit

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

Is there a way to scale a report to fit in the printable area? Like Adobe Reader. My reports are in A4 size, but they're to close too the page borders. I bought a new printer, and the printable area is smaller than the old one, and there are some cuts in the report.

I didn't change the paper size or whatever, just the printer.

Here is an image of what's happening: [image: Reports]

Comment: Only control I remember is page margins, but I don't see how that would change in the report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas:

- By default, Crystal tends to have the Use Default Margins option selected - the default margins are not always set to the maximum printable area of the page. The answer could be as simple as unchecking the Use Default Margins option in the Page Setup dialog (from the File > Page Setup... menu) and adjusting the margins to match the previous printer's default settings.
- Alternatively, some printer drivers include a scale to fit option - if this is available, it should be possible to set it within the Print Setup dialog (from the File > Printer Setup... menu option) by clicking the Properties button immediately beneath the printer name and specifying the appropriate option within the printer driver's properties.
- A possible workaround (if neither of the previous ideas works) would be to export the printer output to PDF (with the *old* printer set as the report printer), and then print the exported PDF document to the new printer from the PDF viewer.